# How to only pay the dependency penalty for the implementation you use in Python?

Tags: python, import, dependencies

I have a fairly simple set of functionality for which I have multiple implementations, e.g., a datastore that could be backed by Redis, MongoDB, or PostgreSQL. How should I structure/write my code so that code that wants to use one of these implementations only needs the dependencies for that implementation, e.g., they don't need to have `psycopg2` installed if they are using the Redis backend.

Here's an example. Assume the following module, `example.py`.

```
class RedisExample(object):
    try:
        import redis
    except ImportError:
        print("You need to install redis-py.")

    def __init__(self):
        super(RedisExample, self).__init__()

class UnsatisfiedExample(object):
    try:
        import flibbertigibbet
    except ImportError:
        print("You need to install flibbertigibbet-py")

    def __init__(self):
        super(UnsatisfiedExample, self).__init__()
```

Here's my Python shell experience:

```
>>> import example
You need to install flibbertigibbet-py
```

Alternately:

```
>>> from example import RedisExample
You need to install flibbertigibbet-py
```

I'd really rather I didn't get that error until I tried to instantiate an `UnsatisfiedExample`. Is there any sort of common way to approach this problem? I've thought about making `example` a package with each backend getting its own module and using a factory function, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something better.

Thanks.

Comment: After having such an amazing Rep. your entire question is in the title... ?

Comment: It might help to focus the title and provide details in the body.  Details help, a little bit of almost-working code to show what you wish would happen is often helpful.

Comment: Sorry guys - I have a newborn, so the ability to focus is here one minute, gone the next. I'll try to revise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you simply put the `import` statement in the `__init__` method of each class? Then it won't be run until you try to make an instance:

```
class UnsatisfiedExample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            import flibbertigibbet
        except ImportError:
            raise RuntimeError("You need to install flibbertigibbet-py")
        super(UnsatisfiedExample, self).__init__()
```

Comment: In addition, you can store the lib inside an instance variable, so that you can access it later inside your class: ```try: import flibbertigibbet; self.fg = flibbertigibbet```

Answer (score 4):

`import` is just another statement, like `for` or `with`. Put it in an `if` statement, possibly behind an abstraction class.

Comment: I revised the question to provide more detail. Could you post an example of the abstraction class idea you mentioned and how that would address my (hopefully clearer now) concern?

Comment: My answer doesn't change. Perform the import when you need it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the client code simply do `from example import RedisExample` instead of `import example`? Because that also triggers the `ImportError`.

Comment: ... No, I'm suggesting that you import it when you need it. As in, just before you need to access a name in it.